# FB profile connectivity

Tags: algorithm

I tried to search for the answer of one problem of my interview. But got no solution. Can anyone help me in this question. Here is the problem Description:

Given two person's name A & B. You know both exist on FB. You have to tell is there any connectivity between them. If connectivity exists then you have to tell the exact path of connectivity.
By Connectivity they mean that B could be a friend of C which is friend of A . In this way the re is a connectivity between A & B and the path would be A -> B- > C

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Bidirectional search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_search).

The main idea:

1. AGroup = {A}, BGroup = {B}.
2. while intersect(AGroup,BGroup) = empty set:

   2.1 Expand every person from AGroup that you have not expanded yet and insert the result to AGroup.

   2.2 Expand every person from BGroup that you have not expanded yet and insert the result BGroup.

   2.3 if AGroup and BGroup have not changed, return "A and B are not connected".
3. Denote S the person in both AGroup and in BGroup.

Now you have the path from A to S, and the path from B to S.

Return A->...->S->...->B.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .. But the main problem in this solution is size of the data .....levels of searching was not defined. This solution is reasonable enough if we want to go down only for one level .... But there could be a chain like friend of friend of friend.. So even if you will define the level depth somewhere around 5 , then also it will set the record count to million to search.....

Comment: @priyas This solution is reasonable for more than 5 levels too because the branching factor is usually decreased. Moreover, you can not do better without any assumptions.